# JAVA- unable to solve void/ String issue

Tags: string, return, void

Thank You for looking at my problem and your helpful suggestion. This simple program I'm writing using Getter Setter, my intention was when user types END it will stop and print input.

Problem: As I run this program it asks for Student name twice and takes the last input. Example

Enter (sp)a name: 
nn
Enter (sp)a name: 
nm
Enter (sp)ID: 
11
Enter (sp)a name: 
END
{nm=11}

My thought: I am assuming this part of the code is causing this

public String takeSPNAME(){

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter (sp)a name: ");
     return this.setSpName(userInput.next());
}
```

However if I use VOID instead of String then I will not be able to use .match option  [while(!(this.takeSPNAME().matches("END")))] void is primitive type.

Can someone point me to what can be done?

Code:

import java.util.*;
public class StudentProfile {

```
public String spName;
public int spID;

public HashMap<String, Integer> hlist= new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public String getSpName() {
    return spName;
}

public String setSpName(String spName) {
    return this.spName=spName ;
}
public int getSpID() {
    return spID;
}
public void setSpID(int spID) {
    this.spID = spID;
}

public void takeSPNAME(){

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter (sp)a name: ");
      this.setSpName(userInput.next());
}

public void takeSPID(){
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter (sp)ID: ");
    this.setSpID(userInput.nextInt());

}

public void printINFO(){

    while(!(this.takeSPNAME().matches("END"))){

        this.takeSPNAME();
        this.takeSPID();
        hlist.put(spName, spID);
    }
    System.out.println(hlist);
}
```

}

---

Since I have not seen any response, I tried to solve this myself. After working few days I changed the code and got rid of Getter Setter. Here is the new code

import java.util.*;

public class StudentProfile {

```
public String spName;
public int spID;


public HashMap<String, Integer> hList= new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public String takespName(){
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter (sp) student name: ");
    return spName= userInput.next();

}
public void printSPinfo1(){

    String myname= this.takespName();


    if((spName).matches("END")){

        System.out.println("EXIT");
    }
    while(!(spName).matches("END")){

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter (sp) student id: ");
        spID=userInput.nextInt();
        this.takespName();
        hList.put(spName, spID);
    }
    System.out.println(hList);
}
```

}

Output:(just like I wanted)

Enter (sp) student id: 
15
Enter (sp) student name: 
END
{bob=14, END=15, aron=11}

Comment: Anyone please... ?  Thanks

Comment: After working 4 days, I have finally solved it myself. I had to change the design a little bit (no longer using Getter Setter). This is what I did